# How is this Quartz Cron Expression executed

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I have a the following;

```
private String cronExpression = "";
private final String jobID = "MyJObID";
...
Scheduler scheduler = ServiceLocator.getInstance().getScheduler();
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(jobID , Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, cronExpression);
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(jobID , Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, MyJob.class);
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

My question is when is this job triggered for the empty cron expression?

Comment: Is this just out of curiosity, or is your application actually doing this? If the latter, what for?

Comment: my application is actually doing this. I have modified some parts of the code and would like to do some tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, found the issue.

After some night of searching i found out that the class was registered in JBoss as a MBean and a value for the cron expression attribute was set to some meaningful value in the deployment descriptor

Sigh

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it works?

Just by looking at the `org.quartz.CronExpression#buildExpression()` method code it looks like an exception should be thrown:

```
        if (exprOn <= DAY_OF_WEEK) {
            throw new ParseException("Unexpected end of expression.",
                        expression.length());
        }

      // exprOn should be equal to SECOND in case of empty String given
```

[checked in Quartz 1.6.0]

Comment: FWIW its sent every morning at 8am

Comment: Looking at the source of Quartz 1.5.1 (this time it's CronTrigger.buildExpression()) the same exception is thrown there. Have you tried to debug and set a breakpoint somewhere there?